# how to orchestrate data lake activities?

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

**How do we orchestrate the execution of stored procedures in data lake?**

**Example**

```
1. execute sproc dbo.abc
2. execute sproc dbo.xyz
3. execute sproc dbo.aaa
```

The question could be more specifically restated: **what integrations does Azure provide in order to be able to execute usql stored procedures? Azure Functions? Events?**

Comment: I wish I could drop 500 on this right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use DataFactory. Its easy and powerfull.

You can create a pipeline of U-SQL activities.

Check this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-data-lake-analytics

Comment: would love your input here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57997672/how-to-combine-different-schemas